# Trouble converting latitude/longtiude to DMS and back

Tags: c, gcc

I've written two functions to convert latitude and longitude back and forth from its components Degrees, Minutes, and Seconds. As far as the method decToDMS() goes, the math seems to be okay its just that my positive/negative signs are off on my minutes and seconds.

For DMStoDec, I'm just barely off in my calculations and I'm not quite sure where the error lies. Here are both code samples:

```
int DMStoDec(double *deg, int degrees, int minutes, double seconds) {
    //test for invalid inputs
    if (deg == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (*deg < -180 || *deg > 180) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Formula is degrees = degrees + minutes/60 + seconds/3600;
    double m;
    double s;
    double d;   
    d = (double) degrees;
    m = (double) minutes / 60;
    s = (double) seconds / 3600;

    *deg = d + m + s;
    printf("DMS to Dec is %lf\n", *deg);

    return 0;
}

int decToDMSint *degrees, int *minutes, double *seconds, double deg) {
    if (degrees == NULL || minutes == NULL || seconds == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (deg < -180 || deg > 180) {
        return 1;
    }
    *degrees = deg;
    deg = deg - trunc(deg);
    // multiply the decimal by 60;
    deg *= 60;
    *minutes = deg;
    // Drop the integer
    deg = deg - trunc(deg);
    deg *= 60;
    *seconds = deg;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
*degrees = deg;
deg = deg - trunc(deg);

// minutes and seconds are >= 0
if (deg < 0)
    deg *= -1;

// multiply the decimal by 60
deg *= 60;
*minutes = deg;
// Drop the integer
deg = deg - trunc(deg);
deg *= 60;
*seconds = deg;
```